# Will Windows 7 work with Bootcamp?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, boot-camp

Will Windows 7 (Home Premium) work with Bootcamp on my iMac 24" Late 2008 (Snow Leopard 10.6.1) successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to report blue screens of death on successive days, after doing a clean install of Snow Leopard and Windows 7 Professional under Boot Camp.  Subsequently all available updates have been downloaded and installed under both OSs, and everything's been fine for last two weeks.  So, extra vigilance on saving work maybe needed if you've just got setup.

Comment: As a follow up I've been running Windows 7 for sometime now and apart from a minor problem I've been having with audio playback everything's worked well (touch wood).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work for sure, I've been using the release version of Windows 7 on my MacBook Pro running the latest Snow Leopard (with similar hardware to your iMac) since it's been available for Computing Science students, and it works like a charm. It even works in VMWare Fusion!

Comment: Windows was designed to run on any computer architecture. It will run under Bootcamp, a virtual machine or any other conventional hardware configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the beta of 7 in bootcamp for ages with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

yes, My friend test it and work fine.
you can install in.